# with js , How to drag and drop the entire Row box inside the Column box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created an html file with 2 button (add row, add column) to add **Row-box** and **column-box**. To create **row-box** click **add row** button , to add **column-box** inside the row, click **add column** and then click any added row-box and **can drag column-box to another row-box** also. I am looking for a solution to **drag the entire row-box inside to another column-box**.

When clicking add row , the row-box appending to the '**contentBox**' id Container

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gph82mfa/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="header">
      <button class="add-row" onclick="addRow()">Add Row +</button>
      <button class="add-column" onclick="addCol()">Add Column +</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content-box" id="contentBox">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Row Addition
var i=0;
let newColNode = null;

function addRow() {    
    const row = document.createElement('div');
    row.className = 'row-block';
    row.id = "b" + ++i;
    document.getElementById('contentBox').appendChild(row);
    row.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        if(newColNode != null)
        row.appendChild(newColNode);
        newColNode = null
    });
    row.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver); 
    row.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter); 
    row.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
    row.addEventListener('drop', Drop);
}

// Row Addition

function addCol() {
    const col = document.createElement('p');
    col.className = 'column-block';
    col.setAttribute('draggable', true);
    col.textContent = `Column`;
    newColNode = col;
    col.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart); 
    col.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd); 
}

// drag and drop

var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var choice = document.getElementsByClassName('row-block');
var dragItem = null;

for (var i of p) {
    i.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
    i.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
}

function dragStart() {
    dragItem = this;
    setTimeout=(()=>this.style.display = "none", 0)
}

function dragEnd() {
    setTimeout=(()=>this.style.display = "none", 0)
    dragItem = null;
}

for(j of choice){
    j.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver); 
    j.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter); 
    j.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
    j.addEventListener('drop', Drop);
}

function Drop(){
    this.append(dragItem);
}

function dragOver(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
}

function dragEnter(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}

function dragLeave(){
    // this.style.borderColor = "none";
}
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    background: #03A9F4;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.main-content {
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    height: 100%;
    background: #fafafa;
}

.each-draggable-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}


.header {
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.content-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    padding: 15px;
}


button {
    background: #000;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.row-block {
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px dashed #848484;
    padding: 20px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.row-block:hover {
    border-color: #2654d1;
}

.column-block {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 2px dashed #848484;

    background-color: #dedede;
    padding: 20px;
}
.column-block:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.column-block:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.container .ex-moved {
    background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.container.ex-over {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.handle {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    cursor: move;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.sidebar .column-block {
    min-height: auto;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.column-block h5 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Attaching the js fiddle along with this.

https://jsfiddle.net/gph82mfa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add events to columns and rows.
https://jsfiddle.net/Lzp3mu5a/

```js
// Row Addition
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
let newColNode = null;

function addRow() {
  const row = document.createElement('div');
  row.className = 'row-block';
  row.setAttribute('draggable', true);
  ++i;
  row.textContent = `Row-${i}`;
  row.id = "row" + i;
  document.getElementById('contentBox').appendChild(row);
  row.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (newColNode != null)
      row.appendChild(newColNode);
    newColNode = null
  });
  row.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
  row.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
  row.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  row.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
  row.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
  row.addEventListener('drop', Drop);
}

// Row Addition

function addCol() {
  const col = document.createElement('p');
  col.className = 'column-block';
  col.setAttribute('draggable', true);
  ++j;
  col.textContent = `Column-${j}`;
  col.id = "col" + j;
  newColNode = col;
  col.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
  col.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
  col.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  col.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
  col.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
  col.addEventListener('drop', Drop);
}

// drag and drop

var dragItem = null;
var dropItem = null;

function dragStart() {
  if (dragItem !== null) return;
  console.log("from: ", this.id);
  dragItem = this;
  setTimeout = (() => this.style.display = "none", 0)
}

function dragEnd() {
  setTimeout = (() => this.style.display = "none", 0)
  dragItem = null;
  dropItem = null;
}


function Drop() {
  if (dropItem !== null) return;
  console.log("to: ", this.id);
  dropItem = this;
  if (dragItem !== null)
    this.append(dragItem);
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}


function dragLeave() {
  // this.style.borderColor = "none";
}
```

Comment: Why `dropItem` should be considered?

Comment: All column-blocks and row-blocks should be draggable and droppable. If you drag a block that is contained inside another row or column, then drap event of those elements occur also. So, you should prevent it and only occur the focused element. And after dropping, you should free the drag and drop item.

Comment: @hcharles25 thanks brother. Thanktou for you valueable time.